# Are there non-periodic continuous functions with this property?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

Suppose $ f$ is a real-valued continuous non-constant function defined on all of $ \mathbb{R}$. Let $ A = \text{image} f $. Suppose also that there is a  $L > 0$ such that for every half open interval $ I \subseteq \mathbb{R} $ with $| I | = L $, $\text{image} f|_{I} = A $. Must $ f$ be periodic?

Comment: sounds like $\tan(x)$ to me.  It doesn't have to be periodic as you can imagine a slight change to the curve at each interval.

Comment: It's not continuous on all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: If by *range* in this case you mean that $f$ takes all real values on a half-open interval $[a,b)$, say, then it cannot be continuous because it has to be bounded on $[a,b]$.

Comment: There seems to have been a lot of confusion caused by the original wording. I have edited to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No; a counterexample is $x\mapsto \sin |x|$ with $A=[-1,1]$ and $L=4\pi$.

Comment: That seems like a cheat, because it's a piecewise function constructed from two periodic functions.  What if we require something stronger than being non-periodic, like there can be no $a$, $b$, and $c$ such that $f(x) = f(x+c)$ for all $x$ in $[a,b)$?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan: What about $\sin(x^3+x)$ with $L=2\pi$ instead, then?

Comment: That also seems to violate the spirit of the question, because while $f(I)$ does technically equal $A$ whenever $|I|=2\pi$, the graph of f passes through the points in $A$ a different number of times in each such interval.  So what if we require in addition that the "multiplicity" of the values in the range must be matched, i.e. if $|I_1| = |I_2| = L$, then for any $y$, the number of times that $f(x) = y$ in $I_1$ must equal the number of times that $f(x) = y$ in $I_2$?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan: That would imply pretty directly that $L$ is a period of $f$ -- if you move the interval any small distance to the right, the values that drop out at the left end must be exactly the same as the ones that enter at the right end.

Comment: But apart from that, how's $(\cos^2 x)^{1+x^2}$ for spirit?

Comment: WolframAlpha doesn't do a very good job of graphing that function, so can you tell me the general characteristics of its graph, and what value of $L$ you're using?  Also, how would you formally prove that my condition implies that the function is periodic?  I see your intuitive argument, but I'm not sure it works over a continuum like the set of real numbers.

Comment: @Keshav: Looks good to me: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28cos+x%29%5e2%29%5e%28x%5e2%2b1%29%2C+-2%3Cx%3C15 with $L=2\pi$.

Comment: @Keshav: Your strong condition implies that $f([x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon))=f([x+L-\varepsilon,x+L+\varepsilon))$, with multiplicity. Due to continuity, the value of $f(x)$ and $f(x+L)$ are both the single element of the intersection of these intervals as $\varepsilon\to0^+$.

Comment: As far as the graph goes, what does the function do between the spikes?  Is it zero or just really low?  And why does my condition imply that $f([x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)) = f([x+L-\epsilon,x+L+\epsilon))$ with multiplicity (or at all for that matter)?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan: You have the expression: $(\cos^2 x)^{1+x^2}$ clearly cannot be zero except where $\cos x$ is zero. And if $f([x-\varepsilon,x+L-\varepsilon))$ and $f([x+\varepsilon,x+L+\varepsilon))$ are identical with multiplicity (by your condition), then of course the same must be possible if you remove $f([x+\varepsilon,x+L-\varepsilon))$ from each of them.

Answer (score 1):

Attaining all real values in each length $L$ interval would mean that the function tends to positive infinity *and* negative infinity in the same bounded interval. This is clearly impossible for a continuous function.

---

**Edit:** This was a response to an earlier iteration of the question, in which it was only specified that the function be continuous. In that case, observe a continuous function on a closed and bounded (i.e., compact) interval achieves its minimum and maximum; thus, taking any closed interval of length $L$, you could not hope to have the function defined at all $x$ *and* attain all real values.